# What are width and height supposed to be in Nez TiledTileLayer?

Tags: monogame

The constructor of [TiledTileLayer.cs](https://github.com/prime31/Nez/blob/master/Nez.Portable/PipelineRuntime/Tiled/TiledTileLayer.cs) takes 4 simply-named arguments. I'm assuming `name` is the layer's name but I can't figure out what `width` and `height` are supposed to represent.

```
public TiledTileLayer( TiledMap map, string name, int width, int height ) {}
```

Is it the width of the map, the width of the tile, the number of tiles? Should I hardcode it or get it from another object?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried figuring it out by reading the class yourself? from the looks of it, they likely mean the width of the map, and they seem to load the tiles based on the map width. The width of the tiles is already defined in the class itself.

Answer (score 1):

So apparently, if anyone else is wondering, according the `populateTilePositions()` method, `width` and `height` represent the number of tile (horizontally and vertically) and not the width and height in pixels.

```
TiledTile[] populateTilePositions()
{
    for( var y = 0; y < height; y++ )
    {
        for( var x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {
            if( tiles[x + y * width] != null )
            {
                tiles[x + y * width].x = x;
                tiles[x + y * width].y = y;
            }
        }
    }

    return tiles;
}
```

The tiles positions are therefore `0,0`, `1,0`, `2,0`, ..., `0,1`, `1,1` etc. until the last one which will be `x-1,y-1`.

This also means that you can simply pass the values from the map object passed as first parameter like so:

```
var tiledMap = content.Load<TiledMap>("mytilemap");
var backgroundLayer = new TiledTileLayer(tiledMap, "layername", tiledMap.width, tiledMap.height);
```

I guess my confusion was due to the fact that those could have been the default values and where not. Maybe something to improve in the future.